# Single bit shifts of multiple __m256i elements

Tags: c++, simd, avx, avx2

I have a 512 bit vector stored as two __m256i elements. Now I need to shift the entire package one single bit (not byte) position left or right. That is, I need a single carry bit transferring between the __m256i elements. Any hints on how to do this as fast as possible? For the moment I can use AVX2 but not AVX-512.

Comment: perhaps `vshufps` or `vpalignr` + `vpermq` to get source data into the right lanes, then shift + OR to insert the new low bit into place after a `vpaddq` or `vpsllq` to shift the original?  That's not very efficient.  Maybe something with `vperm2i128` + `vpalignr` can be usable to get up the right input for each lane?  But `vpalignr` is an in-lane byte shift.

Comment: If you don't bottleneck on loads+stores, I would also consider storing both registers to memory and reloading it into two new registers (with 1, 2, 4 or 8 bytes offset). Then shift the original one bit to the left (or add it to itself) and the reloaded (n*8-1) bits to the right and bit-or the results. (Obligatory rant about Intel intrinsics: "Of course", `_mm256_slli_si256` does 128bit shifting ...)

Comment: To clarify "as fast as possible" could you give some context? How do you get the inputs and what are you doing with the output? And what CPU are you running on? In the title you write "multiple" elements: Is it always two or can it be more/arbitrarily many?

Comment: I have a packed 512 x 3000-5000 binary image containing randomly spaced objects. A 512-bit mask sweeps along the image while counting the number of lines where the mask doesn’t hit anything, i.e. where an AND gives 0. The thing is that the sweep needs to be done several times at slightly different angles so the mask, or the image, needs to be shifted one bit position every N’th line where N is varying but not less than say 20.

Comment: At a first glance it seemed most natural to shift the mask but I realize that it would be better to “shift” the image on the byte level by an unaligned load and on the bit level by pre-generating eight different versions of my mask.

Comment: Even if you go with 8 pre-generated versions of the mask, I would load them using unaligned loads, instead of the data. And the main optimization question is probably how to elegantly accumulate the result of masking 512 bits -- for 256 bits this could be a simple `vptest` and an `adc` (if you invert the mask). For 512 bit you need to either combine the two halves before executing `vptest`, or do some clever `adc` juggling (e.g., something like `vptest (~mask0), input0; adc eax,eax; vptest (~mask1),input1; adc eax,#0; shr eax,1'`. Or maybe branching is actually faster here ...

Comment: As it turns out, I can probably keep the width of my mask below 256 even if the width of the image is 512 or even more. So as you say, a `vptest` and an `adc` will do in the innermost loop.

Comment: @ErikA. in that case, I agree that pre-calculating 8 masks and doing unaligned loads on the image is likely the most efficient option. `vptest` has a max throughput of 1, so the latency of `adc` actually does not matter (if it did, you could use two accumulator registers). You need to pay some attention when the mask moves out of the image area. But this diverged a lot from your original question.